# What's the meaning of $S:\{(x,y,z)|x+y+z=16\ \cap x^2+y^2\leq 16\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$S:\{(x,y,z)|x+y+z=16\ \cap x^2+y^2\leq 16\}$

What's the meaning of this S obejct graph wise?

Comment: Can it be assumed this is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you already know about this set, if anything?

Comment: The intersection of a plane and a cylindre.

Comment: It must be an ellipse + its interior

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+y^2\le 16$ is the set of the points on the surface of the cylinder and its internal points.

$x+y+z=16$ is the set of points which lie on a plane.

The intersection is an ellipse and its internal points.

---

$$...$$
[image]